# react native':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' dependencies of null. java.io.IOException: The filename directory nameor volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: react-native

#### FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I use npx create-react-native-app to create a new project. Then use yarn android

**result**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbzh6.png)

```
thisis local.properties sdk.dir = C:\Users\Peterpan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
I use sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\Peterpan\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk -> But it didn't work for me. 
node ->v20.9.0
java -version ->11.0.20
yarn ->1.22.19
```

this buildscript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRRsZ.png)